# Encriptar String C#

Tags: c#

Tenho o codigo abaixo que desencripta um valor X exemplo (|xB779A:6AA6=@6::@7 e ficaria http://seusite.com) porem eu nao sei como faço para fazer o inverso, queria fazer um aplicativo que encripta esse valor X do exemplo.

tipo tenho o valor http://www.seusite.com.br e queria encriptar esse valor

segue o codigo

```
private static string Descrypt(string source, short shift)
    {
        int num = Convert.ToInt32('\uffff');
        int num2 = Convert.ToInt32('\0');
        char[] array = source.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            int num3 = Convert.ToInt32(array[i]) + shift;
            if (num3 > num)
            {
                num3 -= num;
            }
            else if (num3 < num2)
            {
                num3 += num;
            }
            array[i] = Convert.ToChar(num3);
        }
        return new string(array);
    }


Webbrowser1.Url = new Uri(Descrypt("|xB779A:6AA6=@6::@7", -8) + "1.1.php", UriKind.Absolute);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este algoritmo de "encriptação" é bem simples. Simplesmente soma o valor de shift ao código do caractere. Para "encriptar", subtraia o valor.

```
private static string Encrypt(string source, short shift)
{
    int num = Convert.ToInt32('\uffff');
    int num2 = Convert.ToInt32('\0');
    char[] array = source.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        int num3 = Convert.ToInt32(array[i]) - shift;
        if (num3 > num)
            num3 -= num;
        else if (num3 < num2)
            num3 += num;
        array[i] = Convert.ToChar(num3);
    }

    return new string(array);
}
```

Exemplo:

```
Console.WriteLine(Decrypt("|xB779A:6AA6=@6::@7", -8));
Console.WriteLine(Encrypt("tp://192.99.58.228/", -8));
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado...